# Argument unpacking with custom __getitem__ method never terminates

Tags: python

Could someone explain what is going on under the hood and why this program does not finish?

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return 1

print(*A())
```

Comment: I guess you need to return `None` for non-existent items.

Comment: How many values do you expect `*A()` to unpack to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This program doesn't finish because the class you defined is iterable, using the *old sequence iteration protocol*. Basically, `__getitem__` is called with integers increasing from 0, ..., n until an `IndexError` is raised.

```
>>> class A:
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return 1
...
>>> it = iter(A())
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
1
```

You are unpacking an infinite iterator, so eventually you'll run out of memory.

From the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) docs:

> Without a second argument, object must be a collection object which
> supports the iteration protocol (the `__iter__()` method), or it must
> support the sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()` method with integer
> arguments starting at 0). If it does not support either of those
> protocols, TypeError is raised.

Comment: Thanks! I dug a bit and found nice explanation of old iteration protocol [here](https://dev.nextthought.com/blog/2018/06/python-old-sequence-iteration-protocol.html#id10)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation of `object.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) it is supposed to raise `IndexError` or `KeyError` when a non-existent elements is requested.

You ignore the `key` and return a constant—so you never indicate that it is finished.

```
class A:
  n = 0
  def __getitem__(self, _):  # ignoring the key
     A.n += 1
     if A.n > 1000:
         raise IndexError()
     return A.n

print(*A())
```

will finish and print up to 1000 - yours never does - when decompositioning your class you are never done.

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... 998 999 1000
```